# Problem with \overlays

Tags: pstricks, overlays, presentations

I latex the following tex. I got error in the line below `\end{slide}` as Undefined control sequence }

I found out that the problem is related to `\overlays`.

```
\documentclass[pdf,umbc4,slideColor,colorBG]{prosper}
\begin{document}

\overlays{5}{%
\begin{slide}{Outline of the talk}

\begin{itemstep}
    \item Introduction
    \item Statement of the main theorem
    \item Technical lemmata
    \item Proof of the main theorem
    \item Conclusions
\end{itemstep}

\end{slide}
}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use the optional argument `pdf`?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
\documentclass[umbc4,slideColor,colorBG]{prosper}
\let\scaleboxto\psscaleboxto
\begin{document}

\overlays{5}{%
\begin{slide}{Outline of the talk}

\begin{itemstep}
    \item Introduction
    \item Statement of the main theorem
    \item Technical lemmata
    \item Proof of the main theorem
    \item Conclusions
\end{itemstep}

\end{slide}
}  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that recent changes to PSTricks have made it incompatible
with Prosper (unmaintained sice 2001 it seems). (I am running Fedora Core
20, but I should think this is not platform specific.)

The immediate problem is that the overlay functionality has been
separated out into a separate package, `pst-ovl`. That can be worked
around by an explicit

```
\usepackage{pst-ovl}
```

Having done that, it turned out some tools for building the slides
were missing. Apparently a missing dependency in some package.
Installing `texlive-pst-tools` solved that:

```
sudo yum install texlive-pst-tools
```

But having done all of this, it turned out that the generated postscript
was flawed leading to an error:

```
Error: /undefined in BOL
```

At this point, after some further fruitless Googling and pondering of
options, I decided to heed the above advice and downgrade to an
earlier version of PSTricks. I opted for:

```
texlive-pstricks-svn29482.2.37-20.fc18
```

Old enough to not incorporate the breaking change for sure, but hopefully
not too old. I also decided to try to downgrade ONLY "pstricks", even though
lots of others depend on it, hence a forced downgrade:

```
sudo rpm -U --oldpackage texlive-pstricks-svn29482.2.37-20.fc18.noarch.rpm
```

This appeared to solve the immediate problem: I could generate slides
with overlays using Prosper again. But I have not tested the interaction
between the old PSTricks package and all the newer dependencies on my
system. Maybe a more thorough downgrade of the entire collection of
PSTricks-related packages would have been better.

Finally, positioning and paper size no longer worked as before, cropping
off the left-hand-side of my slides. Not unusably much, but enough to
look strange. I'm going via postscript, and fiddling with dvips parameters
helped. Specifically, I had to add the options

```
-t a4
```

and

```
-O 0cm,-1cm
```

to "dvips".

Now things look acceptable. But it all appears very brittle, and who knows
what might break next. The way to go is likley to switch to a more modern
slide package, like Beamer, that is actively maintained. However, that is
painful if one has lots of "legacy" propser slides (as I do). Another
option might be to try to figure out how to patch the old Prosper package.

Hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: You do not need to install packages "by hand". Run your update manager and it should be done.

Comment: But this was not an update, but a downgrade to a specific older package. How can the update manager do that automatically?

Comment: As far as I know the latest Ubuntu can also run the `tlmgr`. Which TeX distribution do you have installed? 2013?

Comment: I am on Fedora 20, texlive. I did try using `yum` first, but it did not seem to know about the package I wanted. Maybe it is limited to only look for packages available for the current distribution. Or maybe I have to read the manual page very carefully to figure out how to install packages from earlier distributions using `yum`. To me, the most important was to quickly try to see if a downgrade of PSTricks might help as a stop-gap measure. It seems it did. But if there is an easier way to downgrade, that would be good to know.

Comment: `pst-ovl`is loaded by `seminar` anyway, no need for loading it explicitely! `prosper` loads `seminar.bg3`_and_ `seminar.bg2` which makes no sense, both define commands of the same name.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar problem after updated the `pstricks` package. Falling back to an older version of `pstricks` worked for me.

Comment: I don't know how useful this is. What version did you update from/fall back to? Did you file a bug report with the package author?

Comment: to @Werner, I observed the issue when updating MacTex (texlive for OS X) 2012->2013. Strictly speaking, it is *not* a bug, but incompatibility between `pstricks` and `prosper` packages.